# error uploading csv file on cloud jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x

I have set up a google cloud account
I want to perform my deep learning much more faster on a jupyter notebook, but 
I cannot find a way to read my csv file
I downloaded it with wget from my github account and afterwards I tried

dataset  = pd.read_csv('/home/user/.jupyter/SIEMENSTRAIN.csv')

but I get the following error

pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 12

Why? When I read it on my laptop using my jupyter notebooks, everything runs well

Any suggestions?

I tried the recommended solutions for this error and I got the next warning

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:1: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  if **name** == '**main**':

When I ran dataset.head() this is what appeared

[image]

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities that could be causing the problem... I would first always make sure that Pandas (pd)'s version is updated and compatible.

The more likely cause is that the CSV itself is not right, so pd.read_csv() is not able to work correctly (thus a Parse Error). This may have something to do with the headers, though I'm not sure what your original CSV file looks like. It's worth playing around with read_csv, for example:

```python
df = pandas.read_csv(fileName, sep='delimiter', header=None)
```

This tampers with 2 things - the delimiter, and if pd is reading a header from CSV or not.

I go through some pd.read_csv() stuff in my [book](https://www.energize.ai/stockprediction/) about Stock Prediction (another cool Machine Learning problem) and Deep Learning, feel free to check it out.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hmm... Could you share with me the contents of the CSV? Is there anything abnormal with it that's making PD read it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you proposed and this is what I got[image]

So, any suggestions? 
I suppose that the path is ok, but it just won't be read properly, or am I wrong?